Should more basic methods of proof be taught BEFORE induction?
Would it help to introduce students to methods of proof more basic than induction, e.g. how to structure a simple proof with a premise and a conclusion, how to generalize, etc.? Maybe start with simple proofs of something like A & B => B & A? Maybe learn to walk before you can run?

My impression is that more basic proof methods usually ARE taught before induction. At least, this is true at every university where I have studied or taught...

I don't think that learning how to argue a tautology like $A \wedge B \implies B \wedge A$ is a good thing to do before learning induction.  Certainly they should learn to prove basic meaningful statements like $3|x \wedge 5|y \implies 15 | (xy)$.  They should understand the basic proof strategies for each connective and quantifier, and how to string them together appropriately.  I like to do this using a relatively informal Fitch style natural deduction system.

I was inspired to raise this question here by one recently posted by a student at another math forum. He was confused about assuming vs. proving in the inductive step. It seemed like he hadn't any training in writing simple proofs, making universal generalizations in particular. Is this a common difficulty?

@StevenGubkin I think A & B => B & A would a good place to start. The proof would be something like: 1. A & B (Premise); 2. A (Split, 1); 3. B (Split, 1); 4. B & A (Join 3, 2); 5. A & B => B  &  A (Conclusion, 1). This would demonstrate that we are NOT proving A & B in line 1. We are provisionally assuming it.

Unless you work at an elite institution, I think you will find that students are mostly incapable of recognizing any value in establishing tautologies in a formal system.  They will learn to jump through the hoops if you force them, but they will not actually understand that they are accomplishing anything.

Not a duplicate, but this is very relevant: Why are induction proofs so challenging for students? Lots of good info there, but "students don't understand that proofs are about statements" has been particularly useful to me.

Everywhere I have seen induction taught, it already follows proofs about things like: propositional logic including universal quantifiers, modus ponens, arguments by contradiction, and some basic statements about sets or divisibility. That does not mean, however, that the students fully grasp these ideas before the class must move on to induction.

It's actually already a standard part of the US algebra 2 class (11th grade and 16-17 year olds).  Agreeably it's at the end and one of the harder topics.  But it is a stereotypical part of the course.  At least when I took that class (in a public high school).
See:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJIn1ZhoBH8
(See the title of the video.)
And algebra 2 comes (stereotypically) after a year of Euclidian geometry, which is extremely proof heavy (much more emphasis on SAS for congruent triangles than volume of pyramids).
Even if you look at "proof books" for math majors (I think based on your website, this is your emphasis), they seem to already have proof by induction fairly far back in the text.  The one book I have seems to have it fairly far back:
https://www.amazon.com/Book-Proof-Richard-Hammack/dp/0989472124
(Hammack Book of Proof, see the images and table of contents: it is chapter 10!)
FWIW, I'm not an expert on proof or on math majors.  But I suspect that some of the difficulty with proof by induction is the algebraic complexity.  Agreeably there is also a subtle concept to deal with.  But it's on top of some algebra.  And humans are not rule-based calculating systems--we are smarter versions of Pavlov's pooch. ;)  Slightly joking, but meaning it, also.  It's one of the reasons why "word problems are hard".  Just more stuff to keep track of.
By algebraic complexity, I mean just the amount of letters and terms floating around.  I also think this is one reason why epsilon delta is hard--just the tediousness of the algebra, on top of the concept. Although not as bad as rotating coordinates.  I'm still traumatized decades later by that part of my semester-long analytic geometry class in high school. Memorizing those formulas and churning problems on a test...with a gazillion ways to go wrong.  No CASes back then!  ;-)
But, induction is not as bad as the rotating coordinates.  So just do a lot of drill. (That worked with the rotations also.)
And there is sort of a side benefit (I think) in that the algebra is similar to dealing with infinite series and terms and the like when doing that (later) chapter in ODEs.

I don't know if proving angle A = angle B in a diagram will prepare a student at all for something like proofs by induction.  A diagram is not a statement in the usual sense.

There were axioms and theorems and definitions and all.  And my teach, back in the 80s, said "this is going to feel different because it's a year of proving things instead of calculating them". And it did.  ;-)

There is no practice in even formulating an initial premise (a statement).  It is all built into a diagram that is usually given IIRC.

Aren't the main theorems of geometry "statements" (of significant general utility), which the students learn to prove using axioms, definitions, and previously proved theorems of geometry?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_geometry  I mean sure, some of the drill is just specific diagrams.  But that is not the whole class.  You still prove each main theorem also.  (And the "diagram drill" is still useful practice of proof also!)

But even if you disagree with the traditional wisdom that high school geometry is an exposure to proof (agree to disagree), didn't any of my other points "sing"?  (1) Induction proof is already part of (good) algebra 2 or "precalc" classes...in HIGH SCHOOL.  (2) Part of the psychological/pedagogical difficulty is the combination of the new/difficult concept with some tedious algebra.  (3) the benefit of drill to build familiarity with "new/difficult concept"s and with "tedious algebra".  (4) Induction proof is NOT the first part of many proof books/course (see the text I linked to!)

There is certainly some good in practicing the application of a list of geometric rules, but if you cannot formulate an initial premise and make universal generalizations, your proof-writing skills are extremely limited. A formal proof of even the basic theorems of geometry is far beyond the scope of any high-school course.

I myself had no problem with proofs by induction in high school. Maybe it is a rare student that gets confused about assuming vs. proving. If it is common, some prior practice formulating a premise in a simple proof and arriving at a universal generalization may help.
